# Gstreamer 1.16.3 plugin on Ubuntu to 1.14.4 Debian

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, debian, gstreamer

I have a Gstreamer bad-plugin work on version 1.16.3, opencv 4.2.0 and Ubuntu 20.04.

I must have to make it work on Debian 10. Gstreamer work perfectly on Debian but not with my plugin.
The plugin make video-stabilization with this process in C++:

https://learnopencv.com/video-stabilization-using-point-feature-matching-in-opencv/

When I launch a simple pipeline :
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! cvvideostab ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

cvvideostab is my gstreamer element with the stabilization algorithm

The error is :

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /build/opencv-ytxPbe/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 9748
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/opencv-ytxPbe/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:9748: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor

Abandon
```

The error come from the cvtColor function :

```
gst_cv_video_stab_transform_ip (GstOpencvVideoFilter * base, GstBuffer * buf,  
    Mat img) //frame
{
    static int i = 0;

    GstCvVideoStab *filter = GST_CV_VIDEO_STAB (base);
    
    static Mat currFrame = img.clone();
    Mat nextFrame = img.clone();
  
    // Point au centre de l'image pour définir si zoom, dezoom ou pas
    Point2f center;
    center.x = (currFrame.cols)/2;
    center.y = (currFrame.rows)/2;

    #if DEBUG_VIDEO
        g_print("center X = %f \n", center.x);
        g_print("center Y = %f \n", center.y);
    #endif
    
    static Video video = Video();

    static UMat grayCurr;
    static UMat grayNext;
    
    cvtColor(currFrame, grayCurr, COLOR_BGR2GRAY); //COLOR_RGBA2GRAY
    cvtColor(nextFrame, grayNext, COLOR_RGB2GRAY); //COLOR_RGBA2GRAY
...
}
```

The function work with a video frame store in img and loop on all of video frame to make stabilization.

I try to debug the frame content with img.channels() and img.type() function.

In ubuntu (work perfectly) i have type = 24 and channels = 4.

On debian (error) I have type=144 and channels = 19.

I think the frame is not similar on Gstreaer 1.16.3 and 1.14.4, but on debian gstreamer 1.16.3 is only with unstable package.

I don't know where come from the error, I think from Gstreamer because version is different and openCv version is similar.
When I launch the python code with a mp4 video or a webcam I have a good result with the algorithm and opencv function work good

When I launch the pipeline with cvvideostab but without video processing, Gstreamer sucess to launch the pipeline and teh element is "transparente":

```
static GstFlowReturn
gst_cv_video_stab_transform_ip (GstOpencvVideoFilter * base, GstBuffer * buf,  
    Mat img) //frame
{

    return GST_FLOW_OK;
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Update gstreamer plugin. I just updating on my raspberry pi today.

Comment: this is a new installation, so I have the last version can I have on my setup for gstreamer and bad-plugin;

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution to launch my pipeline correctly but the result are less good that on Ubuntu

```
gst_cv_video_stab_transform_ip (GstOpencvVideoFilter * base, GstBuffer * buf,  
    IplImage * img_r) //frame
{
    static Mat img = cvarrToMat(img_r);
    static int i = 0;
    ...
}
```

Many elements of opencv plugin use IplImage Class class rather than Mat Class, if I convert in Mat object it work correctly.

The channels and the type of the frame are the same that ubuntu (4 and 24)

I'm not really satisfied with this "bandage", if anyone has a better solution I take it !

Thanks